# Unable to use Apache Ignite persistence in OpenDaylight

Tags: akka, ignite, opendaylight, akka-persistence

I am trying to replace the default LevelDB in OpenDaylight with Apache Ignite which i am unable to do after making changes to the akka.conf file and deploying the akka-persistence-ignite jar that i found  here.
https://github.com/Romeh/akka-persistance-ignite

I am going through ODL source code and put some Log.debug/print statements in some classes of the sal-distributed-datastore module.

The one shown below is a portion of the outcome i got after putting the print statement in the constructor of the class  ActorSystemProviderImpl residing in org/opendaylight/controller/config/yang/config/actor_system_provider/impl. I printed the contents of the config object by config.entrySet().

```
akka.persistence.snapshot.ignite.class=Quoted("akka.persistence.
ignite.snapshot.IgniteSnapshotStore"),

akka.persistence.snapshot -   store.local.class=Quoted("org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.persistence.Loca
lSnapshotStore"),  

akka.persistence.journal.ignite.cache-prefix=Quoted("akka-

journal"), ignite.peerClassLoadingEnabled=ConfigBoolean(false),  

akka.akka.persistence.snapshot-

store.plugin=Quoted("akka.persistence.snapshot.ignite"), 

akka.persistence.journal.ignite.cache-backups=ConfigInt(1), 

akka.persistence.snapshot.ignite.cache-prefix=Quoted("akka-snapshot"),                                    

akka.persistence.journal.ignite.plugin-dispatcher=Quoted("ignite-dispatcher"),
akka.persistence.journal.ignite.class=Quoted("akka.persistence.ignite.journal.IgniteWriteJournal")
```

I wanted to know why the class  akka.persistence.ignite.journal.IgniteWriteJournal is not being called anywhere. In which part of the ODL source code are the journal and snapshot objects created ? Where exactly is LevelDB journal chosen ? Does it have anything to do with the
ActorSystem.create() method being used in the class ActorSystemProviderImpl ?

Comment: As I can see from akka-persistance-ignite sources provided, it should start Apache Ignite instance inside IgniteFactoryByConfig#apply(), can you check if you have IGNITE_HOME system property specified and correctly pointing to Ignite installation and you got directories created under IGNITE_HOME/work directory after ODL startup?

Answer (score 1):

ODL does not create the journal and snapshot instances - this is done by akka internally at some point during actor system startup based on the configuration in akka.conf. In fact ODL is not even aware of the persistence backend - akka hides this via API abstractions.

I'm assuming the ODL Shards startup successfully in which case there must be **some** persistence backend configured and instantiated. If the default LevelDB is being used then there will be "journal" and "snapshots" directories created under the karaf root directory. So if you do not see these directories created after ODL successfully starts up then it isn't using LevelDB. If so, then assume it's using ignite - as to why it's not logging your print statements in the constructors - maybe you didn't properly deploy the re-built library with your changes? I'm not familiar with ignite at all but shouldn't there be some external artifact that indicates ODL is using ignite, eg a file, database table?

Comment: Yes. The "journal" and "snapshot" directories are created implying the default LevelDB being used. But if the custom class "IgniteJournal" is not being used why exactly isn't sal-distributed-datastore  failing? Can you tell in which part of the sal-distributed-datastore module's source code is the default LevelDB being used?

Comment: As I mentioned ODL does not interact directly with LevelDB or any persistence backend - it interfaces with akka's API abstractions - akka handles instantiating the persistence backend internally.